# Entity Framework trying to use methods to create joins help needed

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I could really use some help, I have the following SQL query that works and have been trying to convert it to Entity Framework to no avail. I am using the Methods rather than the other option, I think that is how you say it.

Anyway the SQL is

```
SELECT c.ACCOUNTID,
       c.TOACCOUNTID,
       fa.ACCOUNTNAME, ta.ACCOUNTNAME,
       p.PAYEENAME

  FROM checking AS c
       LEFT JOIN
       ACCOUNT AS fa ON c.ACCOUNTID = fa.ACCOUNTID
       LEFT JOIN
       ACCOUNT AS ta ON c.TOACCOUNTID = ta.ACCOUNTID
       LEFT JOIN
       PAYEE AS p ON c.PAYEEID = p.PAYEEID
 WHERE c.ACCOUNTID == 1 OR 
       c.TOACCOUNTID == 1;
```

So far I have managed to get it this far.

```
            var checking =
                db.Transactions
                .Where(item => item.ACCOUNTID == LookupAccount || item.TOACCOUNTID == LookupAccount)
                .GroupJoin(db.PAYEE,
                    transaction => transaction.PAYEEID,
                    payee => payee.PAYEEID,
                    (check, payee) => new { Payee = payee }
                ).SelectMany(
                    transaction => transaction.Payee.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                    (transaction, payee) => new { Payee = payee })

                .Select(item => new
                {
                    ToAccount = item.ToAccount.AccountName
                    FromAccount = item.FromAccount.AccountName
                    Withdrawal = 0,
                    Deposit = 0,
                    Payee = item.Payee.PAYEENAME
                }).ToList();
```

The issue I have now, is that I am not sure I understand how joins work in this manner, every time I try to get the 2 other joins in I end up falling flat on my face.

When I add this to the above code, the Payee section is out of whack and I don't understand why. I know it has to do with the select new {} section, I could really use some help understanding how this works.

```
                .Join(db.ACCOUNT,
                    check => check.ACCOUNTID,
                    account => account.ACCOUNTID,
                    (check, fromaccount) => new { FromAccount = fromaccount }
                )
```

### Models

Transaction

```
public partial class Transaction
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int AccountID { get; set; }

    public int? ToAccountId { get; set; }

    public int PayeeId { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "numeric")]
    public decimal TransAmount { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "numeric")]
    public decimal ToTransAmount { get; set; }

    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
}
```

Account

```
public partial class Account
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Account()
    {
        Transaction = new HashSet<Transaction>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int AccountId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string AccountName { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Transaction> Transaction { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Properly designed classes don't need JOINs in entity framework - you work with navigation properties. It's one its strengths. What do your models look like?

Comment: The models where created from using the code first from database, from the same database that the normal SQL works on. While I understand what you are saying, this is a special case where I am using the SQL to generate everything that I need. And what do you mean by properly designed classes? I still need to the account name from both the to and from account in the query and the only way I see  how to do that is with the joins.

Comment: Show the generated Checking POCO. If you reverse engineered it, it should have a navigation property for FromAccount and ToAccount 
 (although the tool may name them funky) which can be easily queried without a JOIN.

Comment: I have added the generated POCO's, I think I know where you are going with this. But every time I tried to do that, I failed. As I am doing a lot of calculation on the fly and manipulation of data to be returned. So hopefully that extra info is what you require.

Comment: I have also edited the select section to give an idea what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created this as an answer, for any one else who may come across this and is learning the syntax.

The reason I wasn't getting it to work was really down to a lack of how EF actually works when joining.

```
Transactions
.Join(Accounts,
    tr => tr.AccountId,
    ac => ac.AccountId,
    (tr, ac) => new { Transaction = tr, ac})

.GroupJoin(Accounts,
    tr => tr.Transaction.ToAccountId,
    ta => ta.AccountId,
    (tr, ta) => new { Transaction = tr.Transaction, Account = ta, FromAccount = tr.ac})
    .SelectMany(
        transaction => transaction.Account.DefaultIfEmpty()
        ,(transaction, account) => new { tt = transaction.Transaction, ToAccount = account, FromAccount = transaction.FromAccount}
    )

.GroupJoin(Payees,
    tr => tr.tt.PayeeId,
    payee => payee.PAYEEID,
    (tr, payee) => new { Transaction = tr, Payee = payee })
    .SelectMany(
        transaction => transaction.Payee.DefaultIfEmpty(),
        (transaction, payee) => new {transaction = transaction.Transaction.tt, FromAccount = transaction.Transaction.FromAccount, ToAccount = transaction.Transaction.ToAccount, Payee = payee })

.Where (x=> x.FromAccount.AccountId == 1 || x.ToAccount.AccountId == 1)

.Select(item => new
    {
        item.transaction.Id,
        TransDate = item.transaction.TRANSDATE,
        Number = item.transaction.TransactionNumber,
        Payee = item.Payee.PAYEENAME,
        Status = item.transaction.Status,

        Category = item.transaction.CategoryId,

        FromAccount = item.FromAccount.AccountName,
        ToAccount = item.ToAccount.AccountName,
        Withdrawal = 0,
        Deposit = 0,
        Notes = item.transaction.Notes
    })
```

The parts that I was not understanding was the relationship in code, from the joins and how the Selects then took over and created a hierarchy through the objects. I really wish that I could have used Navigation here, but from my understanding of Navigation's there needs to be a relationship between the columns and nearly all the fields being joined on here, can be null and therefore a foreign key would not satisfy the requirements for a Navigation.

I am still convinced there is a better way, but for now I have placed this here for others who are still learning and wish to see a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work as a comment, but it might get you further. You have 2 FK in your tx class so you need 2 navigation properties:

```
public partial class Transaction
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // Key by convention

    public int FromAccountID { get; set; }
    public virtual Account FromAccount { get; set; }

    public int? ToAccountId { get; set; }
    public virtual Account ToAccount { get; set; }

    public int PayeeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Payee Payee { get; set; }

    public decimal TransAmount { get; set; }
    public decimal ToTransAmount { get; set; }
}

public partial class Account
{
    public Account()
    {
        Transaction = new HashSet<Transaction>();
    }

    public int AccountId { get; set; }  // Key by convention

    [Required]
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string AccountName { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("FromAccount")]
    public virtual ICollection<Transaction> TransactionsFrom { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("ToAccount")]
    public virtual ICollection<Transaction> TransactionsTo { get; set; }
}
```

Now your query becomes:

```
var checking =
    db.Transactions
    .Include(tx => tx.Payee)
    .Include(tx => tx.FromAccount)
    .Include(tx => tx.ToAccount)
    .Where(tx => tx.FromAccountId == lookupAccountId || tx.ToAccountId == lookupAccountId)
    .Select(tx => new
    {
        ToAccountName = tx.ToAccount.AccountName
        FromAccountName = tx.FromAccount.AccountName
        Withdrawal = tx.ToTransAmount,
        Deposit = tx.TransAmount,
        PayeeName = tx.Payee.PAYEENAME
    }).ToList();
```

https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/

Comment: Do I need to do anything to my DBContext file, because that looks extremely clean and what I seem to be trying to do. When I ran this with sample data, I got null values for the FromAccount and ToAccount

Comment: So to see if I was understanding this, I created a whole brand new database and used just these models and data. I noticed that inside the tables where 3 new columns. Is it possible to do this without creating those new columns, As the old database, is actually existing and in production I don't see how creating more columns is a good thing and something my DB Admin will not allow. Oh and I had to remove the includes from your example as it would not run with them in it.

Comment: Ok I have read up on Navigation and it is not a solution for me in this case and my original question still stands. My understanding is that Navigation only works with foreign keys that has a direct relationship with data that exists. In other words, the column can't be null. Which is why I was doing what I was doing, now I don understand that this generates the Join on the table, but only at the expense of having a foreign key assigned. So unless there is a way to do this on a database that can not have extra columns added, I need an solution to my original question.

Comment: OK, that is a lot to digest :) "My understanding is that Navigation only works with foreign keys that has a direct relationship with data that exists. In other words, the column can't be null." - No, that is not true. `int?` (nullable) is used to indicate that the relationship is optional. It is true, however, that EF6 only works with primary keys and foreign keys. If that is the case, then you just have to tell EF what fields to use. You get extra fields like `Account_Id` when it is unable to identify the proper FK.

Comment: Sounds like yours is a modeling issue. If the database is properly designed and you reverse engineer it you should get working code. If the database does not have formal PK/FK relationships, EF6 won't work and you will need JOINs.

Comment: How do you tell it which fields to use, because every time I try with the sample you gave, it has created a new column in the table. I understand the int? means nullable, but it still creates a foreign key for me. As I said the database is properly designed and in production, the code sample you gave, on my test database (mirror of production data with samples) created the extra column. If I removed the data, it creates a foreign key and extra column. So I maybe missing something, simple.